# GoogleApiAvailability isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returns SUCCESS, play services not installed

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I am debugging on a simulator that does not have google play services installed trying to test error handling.

```
GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(applicationContext)
```

is returning SUCCESS when google play services is not installed on the device.  As such when I go to my map screen I get a message saying

> "App is having trouble with Google Play services. Please try again"

Why is isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returning success in this case?  I would like to make sure play services, specifically maps is installed and is the most recent version my app needs.  However the above call returns success when it shouldn’t.

**EDIT**: Running on a Nexus 4 Android 5.1 Simulator.

I tried running on a newer version (Nexus 5, Android 7) simulator and isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returned an error as expected and I was able to show the error dialog.  Is this GoogleApiAvailability not compat with the older version?

**EDIT**: This is also happening on an old HTC One running 5.1 as well.  Is there a know bug in GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable?